# Angular Resolve is running but View is not rendered. No error in console log

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

```
$routeProvider.when(
    '/view2', {
        templateurl:'view2.html',
        resolve:{
            getController: function($q) {
                console.log('Resolving...');
                var defer = $q.defer();
                require(['ctrl2'], function(util) {
                    console.log(defer);
                    defer.resolve();
                    console.log(defer);
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
        },
        controller: 'view2Controller'
    }
)
```

In this I am not getting any error but my html is not rendered. I am not understanding what error could be in route.

Comment: Sorry for missing enters.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a $routeChangeError event handler to catch the error. It's probably something to do with your resolve.

Something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection){
    console.log(rejection);
});
```

Here is a quick video from [egghead.io](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbqRJQZBF3Q&ucbcb=1) on this